# Computing the top 5 SCC(Strongly Connected Components) components in a Directed graph

Tags: java, directed-graph

I am stuck on this problem where I have to compute the size of top 5 strongly connected components.

**By top 5 I mean the top 5 in size(number of vertices)**

The link to edges of the directed graph is [here.](http://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/algo1/programming_prob/SCC.txt)

This is the code that I have used but my answer is coming wrong.The problem is that when I run the code on small graphs, it gives me correct answer but when I run it on the text file provided in a link of the given porblem, the answer is coming wrong.

**The size of top 5 SCC as computed by my code is coming wrong.**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class SCC
{
 private ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> adj_list;
 private ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> adj_list2;
 private LinkedList<Integer> top_5;
 private BufferedReader br;
 private Stack<Integer> st;
 private boolean second_dfs=false;
 private char []visited;
 private  int size=0;
 private int not_again=-1;
 public void create_graph()throws IOException
 {
     String s;
     String []arr;
     adj_list=new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
     visited=new char[875714];
     for(int i=0;i<875714;++i)
      {adj_list.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());visited[i]=48;}
     br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("P4.txt"));
     while((s=br.readLine())!=null)
     {
         arr=s.split(" ");         
         adj_list.get(Integer.parseInt(arr[0])-1).add(Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
     }
     st=new Stack<Integer>();
     top_5=new LinkedList<Integer>();
 }
 public void rev_graph()
 {
     int i;
     ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> g1;
     g1=new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
     for(i=0;i<adj_list.size();++i)
      g1.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
     for(i=0;i<adj_list.size();++i)
      for(int e:adj_list.get(i))
       g1.get(e-1).add(i+1);
     adj_list=new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>(g1);
 }
 public void DFS(int v)
 {
     if(second_dfs==true)
     {++size;}
     visited[v-1]=49;     
     for(int e:adj_list.get(v-1))
      if(visited[e-1]==48)
       DFS(e);
     if(second_dfs==false)
     st.push(v);
 }
 public void give_SCC()
 {    
     second_dfs=true;int done=0;
     for(int i=0;i<875714;++i)
     {visited[i]=48;}
     while(!st.isEmpty())
     {
      size=0;
      int v=st.pop();
      if(visited[v-1]==48)
       {DFS(v);}
      if(size!=0)
       top_5.add(size);      
     }
 }
 public static void main(String []args)throws IOException
 {
     SCC obj=new SCC();
     obj.create_graph();
     obj.adj_list2=new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>(obj.adj_list);
     obj.rev_graph();
     obj.DFS(1);     
     obj.adj_list=new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>(obj.adj_list2);
     obj.give_SCC();
     Collections.sort(obj.top_5);
     for(int i=obj.top_5.size()-1;i>=obj.top_5.size()-5;--i)
      System.out.println(obj.top_5.get(i));
 } 
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question. You also haven't told us what isn't working. Your link requires a coursera account to view.

Comment: @BoDidely Made the edits. Inform me if the link is still not working.

Comment: @BoDidely I would not be asking, If i had known what isn't working.

Comment: your link is now just a massive text file. There's a difference in not knowing what the issue is and just saying "it's not working". "not working" could mean wrong output, errors, crashing, long run times, etc

Comment: @BoDidely This text file contains the edges of directed graph. Look man I already told that the top 5 sizes  of SCC as computed by my code are being evaluated wrong by coursera site. Kindly read entire question and then resort to comments.

Comment: You have yet to explain what your code is supposed to do. Your  link is a text file of meaningless numbers. We can not see the question on coursera. Kindly read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and good luck with your problem.

Comment: @BoDidely I think you are unaware of what are strongly connected components in Directed Graphs.

Comment: @BoDidely My friend, they are not meaningless numbers, they are directed edges.